# Remove subdirectory from the url makes page not load (404 error)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the directory from the url to go from www.mysite.com/pages/test.php to www.mysite.com/test.php

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# externally redirect /dir/foo to /foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/
RewriteRule pages/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC,R]

# internally forward /foo to /dir/foo
# WHAT GOES HERE?
```

It shows www.mysite.com/test.php in the url but the page doesn't load! And if I remove the htaccess code, the page www.mysite.com/pages/test.php loads no problem..

Please help me figure this out! All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got **mod_rewrite** enabled

Comment: how do i do that on godaddy and on localhost xampp? I read that godaddy already has mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: For Windows platform: To activate the module, the following line in httpd.conf needs to be active:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
*Restart apache

For Linux Platform:
a2enmod rewrite

*Reload all apache config files:
service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps
get the file path by `__FILE__` php magic constant
copy file
and delete old file

```
<?php $file = __FILE__; $newfile = '/';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n"; }  delete("$fil
e"); ?>
```

Comment: I don't want to copy the file over though.. I want it to stay in pages/ on my server but I want the url to remove pages/